How to read kafka messages via Postman?
I want to test kafka messages from different producers.
How can I get kafka messages in Postman?

Postman is an HTTP Client, but Kafka is not an HTTP Server.
You'll need to install an additional service such as a Kafka REST Proxy to translate HTTP requests to Kafka consumer calls.
